# envoy proxy running on localhost works fine from curl, but times out from golang "hey" tool

Tags: networking, curl, proxy, golang

I'm stepping through some Envoy tutorials (probably doesn't matter if you don't know what that is). I'm doing this on my Ubuntu VM (Windows 11 host) and I'm behind a corporate firewall.

We run a specific version of Envoy by running a "func-e" command line, which is a tool for dynamically installing and running a specific version of Envoy. The output of this shows that it's listening on port 10000.

In another shell, I can run "`curl http://localhost:10000`" and it returns the expected output from the Envoy proxy.

In that same shell, I am trying to use a golang tool called "hey", which is a simple load testing tool. You simply give it the url you want to bang on and it returns the results.  In this case, I'm running it with a trivial configuration, like this:

```
hey -n 1 -c 1 http://localhost:10000
```

This says to send one request, with a single worker.  What this does is time out, after the preconfigured 20 second timeout.

If I first disconnect my laptop from the VPN and run this test, it works fine.

I would think this problem has something to do with the proxy settings in the shell, specifically the "no_proxy" variable.  In that comma-separated list, I have both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" (just in case, the "NO_PROXY" variable has the same value).

Comment: what happens when you directly ping 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: Actually, I managed to resolve this. I forgot to update this. What happened is that for some reason my /etc/hosts file was empty. Once I added it with an entry for localhost, it worked fine. It's curious that curl didn't have any trouble with that, but "hey" did.

Answer (score 1):

If it matters, I managed to resolve this. For some reason that VM had a completely empty /etc/hosts file. Once I added an entry for localhost, "hey" worked fine.  I find it curious that "curl" had no trouble with that.

Comment: curl doesn't have trouble with that because it doesn't check /etc/hosts for localhost, the localhost value is hardcoded: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2021/05/31/curl-localhost-as-a-local-host/

Comment: I sort of figured that out by implication, but thanks for confirming that.